# c# dynamic wizard in page_init giving duplicate id error

Tags: c#, sql

I'm adding dynamic textboxes to an asp wizard and setting the textbox ids to match an id from an sql server table. I've checked that the ids are all unique and they are but i keep getting the following error when i click from on wizard step to another.

I need the textbox ids to match the unique ones in the database as i'm live posting the data back using ajax. It's definitely the textbx ids that are causing the error.

```
protected void Page_Init()
{
    play1(null,null);
}

protected void play1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var wizsteps = sdc.usp_WizSteps().ToList();

    foreach (var step in wizsteps)
    {      
        WizardStep ws = new WizardStep();
        ws.ID = step.SectionId;
        ws.Title = step.SectionName;
        wz1.WizardSteps.Add(ws);
        ws.Title = step.SectionName;

        Table tbl = new Table();
        ws.Controls.Add(tbl);
        //tbl.ID = UniqueID;
        ///End of step
        var conts = sdc.usp_WizStepContent(int.Parse(step.SectionId)).ToList();

        foreach (var cont in conts)
        {
            string txt = cont.strText;
            //DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            TableRow tr = new TableRow();

            tbl.Rows.Add(tr);
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lbl = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label();
            lbl.Text = txt;
            TableCell td = new TableCell();
            tr.Controls.Add(td);
            td.Controls.Add(lbl);

            if (cont.InputType == "Textbox")
            {

                TableCell tdi = new TableCell();
                tr.Controls.Add(tdi);
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox tb = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox();
                tdi.Controls.Add(tb);
                tb.ID = cont.id.ToString();
                tb.CssClass = "changable";
                tb.Text = cont.id.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    wz1.ActiveStepIndex = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

my bad. Was duplicating id between a wizard step and a textbox.